# Fetching data with axios from a fake API into a Vuex store doesn't produce the desired outcome

Tags: vue.js, axios

This is my **store.js** code which contains an array named posts which is getting the data from the api

```js
export const store=new vuex.Store({
  state:{    
    posts:[],    
  },
  mutations:{
    getallpost(state,posts) {
      state.posts = posts
    }
  },    
  actions: {    
    getallpost: ({commit}) =>{
      var self =this;
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')    
        .then(function (response) {
        commit(self.posts=response.data)
         commit(console.log('Data: ',response.data));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },    
  }
});
```

This is my **mainpage.js** code: here i am mapping the actions and the state still i am not getting the data displayed on my window

```js
import {mapActions} from 'vuex'
import {mapState} from 'vuex'
import {store} from "../../store/store";
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: 'Mainpage',
  components:{Counter,Result,store},
  data(){
    return{
      posts:[],
    }
  },
  methods:{
  ...mapActions([
      'getallpost']),
    ...mapState([
      'getallpost'
    ])
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

They way you are committing is incorrect. The first argument is a string of the mutation name, the second one is the value.

Your commit in your store should look like that in your action:

```
commit('setPosts', response.data)
```

Note that I've renamed your mutation from `getallpost` to `setPosts` as this makes it semantically more accurate and avoids naming collisions, so basically:

```
  mutations:{
    setPosts(state, posts) {
      state.posts = posts
    }
  },
```

That should do the job of storing the data. Also, get rid of the `var self = this`. When using store you never want to use `this`, the current state of the store will always be given to your mutation through the parameter in the function, to ensure that everything runs synchronous without side-effects.

So far so good. Now in order to be able to receive the fetched posts from your store, you need a getter in your store module:

```
  getters: {
    getPosts: state => state.posts,
  },
```

Finally add the getter to your component's methods:

```
...mapGetters({
  storePosts: 'getPosts'
})
```

You can now use the posts in your template by simply using `{{ storePosts }}`

Comment: I tried this as well but still the api's data is not getting displayed on my main page

Comment: The way I've described it is certainly the correct way. You need some debugging then. 1. are you sure the data coming from the api is in the correct format (take a look at your console.log and move it out of the commit, that line also doesn't make sense). 2. Is the data really represented in your store the way you want it? Check out the vue browser extension, it'll let you display that. 3. Are you displaying the data correctly in your template in the correct format? 4. Are there any errors occuring in your browser's console? Also, have you really made all changes to your app as described?

Comment: i am getting this displayed on my window:  function(){[nativecode]} instead of the data

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have not implemented the getter as described in my answer and using the template syntax I've provided. Please read my answer and implement everything exactly the way as described.

Comment: I checked each and every thing this is actually not working for me !!